# How to write a character only once in textbox?

Tags: c#, textbox, character

I'm making a textbox to input some `Product`'s Price, and I don't want the user to input `"."` more than once. `"."` can not be the first character (which I know how to do). But I need to make the textbox accept this character "." not more than once. How ? And no, I don't want to use `MaskedTextBox`.

Comment: And why don't you want to use MaskedTextBox? Particular reasons (problems with masks) might help to figure out the solution.

Comment: MaskedTextBox is great in handling such case.

Comment: the title is difference but the purpose is the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310137/allowing-only-digits-in-a-textbox-not-working-c-sharp/14310202#14310202

Answer (score 2):

Put it in `KeyPress` event in your textbox.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    string inputChar = e.KeyChar.ToString();
    if (inputChar == ".")
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }

        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How well would this do if you paste text with two dots?

Comment: @WozzeC, Currently, listener only handles a keystroke. So, one can easily paste a couple of dots.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox1.Text.IndexOf('.') != textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf('.'))
  {
     MessageBox.Show("More than once, not allowed");
     textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
  }
}
```