# Regex to get values of format Number-Decimal-Number (eg 1.2)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to ensure that a textbox is having a specific format entered against it... Number from a variable then a Decimal Point then any other number (1.10, 2.6 etc...) The important bit is that the first number should come from a variable then it must be a decimal followed by another number.

I have not been able to find anything too specific and the REGEX functionality looks to require a bit of investigation of how it all works... If I can get a quick result here would be great though!

I instinctively (although didnt expect it to work) tried:

```
If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txbCriterionNo.Text, OutcomeNo.ToString() + "." + "^[0-9]+$") Then
...
```

where OutcomeNo is an integer variable - so I hope you can see what I am aiming to get. So, the format MUST be integer variable - decimal point then another integer value.

What should work:

**1.5** or **5.42** or **10.5**

What shouldn't work:

**.14** or **a.1** or **1.c**

etc...

Thanks!

Comment: It may be that Regex is not the answer - I would therefore be interested to hear any other suggestions on how to enforce this rule.

Comment: Please give two concrete input examples: one that matches and one that doesn´t match your condition

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774890/textbox-validation-for-allow-one-value-c-sharp

Comment: I have made an edit to include more details...

Comment: I realize that my code wouldn't work as it does not follow the REGEX convention - but I hope that is enough to show what I am looknig for in some kind of laymans way.

Comment: instead of regex you need textbox text changed event. refere to question posted for how to to it. only addtion is that it has to start with number. if you have problems translating, i can do it.

Comment: `^\d+\.\d+$` should be `numbers.numbers` if decimal is optional put `\.\d+` in an optional grouping.

Comment: Thanks Claudius - I have taken a look at this so may give it a go. I would prefer not to postback for each keypress if possible so may rip the string apart to its parts and check each one accordingly. If that works I will post the fix on here.

Comment: chris85 - that is amazing... A good part of the way there! If I combine that with a substring for the characters before the decimal point to match my variable I think that will do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris85 pointed me in the right direction, but I also needed to ensure that the first number matched a variable value so I have arrived at the following which works a treat...

```
If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txbCriterionNo.Text, "^\d+\.\d+$") And txbCriterionNo.Text.Substring(0, Convert.ToInt32(InStr(txbCriterionNo.Text, "."))) = OutcomeNo Then
```

Here we are fistly using the regex "^\d+.\d+$" to make sure the format is correct [number][decimal][number] and then a second check get the position of the decimal and using that to get the substring we want to compare against my variable OutcomeNo.

Thanks all!!

Comment: If the first number needs to match a variable couldn't you concatenate that value into the regex? Not familiar with vb.net but maybe something like `"^" + txbCriterionNo.Text + "\.\d+$"`?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was looking for - not had the chance to try your suggestion but will give it a go. I tried a few things similar to no avail... Will keep you posted though!

Answer (score 0):

TextBox This will allow only `digits` and `dot` to be enetered.  And it will have to start with a digit.

```
 Private Sub txtValue_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtValue.KeyPress
   Dim txtValue As txtValue = DirectCast(sender, txtValue)
   If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And txtValue.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0) ) Then
      e.Handled = True
      If txtValue.Text.StartsWith(".") Then
         txtValue.Text = ""
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```