# Allow only {'delete' , 'backspace' , one '.' , '-' , numbers '0 to 9'} on a textbox C#/winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to modify the following code in order to allow only {'delete' , 'backspace' , one '.' , one '-' sign in the beginning of input , numbers '0 to 9'} on a textbox C#/winforms:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    // only allow one decimal point
    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

any help please?

Comment: This is possible, but it's truly **AWFUL** for usability. Typically instead you're _much_ better off allowing any keystroke, checking this at the point where you complete an action (button click, page submit, etc), and using the keypress event only to _show immediate feedback_ on whether the final result will be okay, without interfering with the user.

Comment: Use a [MaskedTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=net-5.0) instead.

Comment: Even if the code looks not very readable or is not optimal, you should check the keys with the OR operator. If you use the AND operator your code is checking whether all conditions are met. Look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs?view=net-5.0

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am trying to minimize the the typing mistakes from low education-level carpenters who asked me to do this restriction, so I thought about this simple way for each textbox I have in my small tool, so it is acceptable for them and easy for me as a beginner programmer.

Comment: @LarsTech I will search for it and try to understand it, thank you for suggestion

Comment: @SebastianSiemens I tried many times with AND & OR, but still cannot reach my target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below method checks if the Character entered is permitted:

```
private bool NotPermittedChar(char character)
{
    return !char.IsDigit(character) && 
        !character.Equals('-') && 
        !character.Equals('.') && 
        !char.IsControl(character);
}
```

Then the below KeyPress method code will perform the relevant checks and conditions you require:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.NotPermittedChar(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    if (this.textBox1.Text.Contains(".") && e.KeyChar.Equals('.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true; //// Don't allow more than 1 decimal place
        return;
    }

    if (this.textBox1.SelectionStart == 0 && e.KeyChar.Equals('.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true; //// Don't allow . to be at the beginning
        return;
    }

    if (this.textBox1.SelectionStart != 0 && e.KeyChar.Equals('-'))
    {
        e.Handled = true; //// Don't allow - in other index than the beginning
        return;
    }
}
```

I added some comments at the side of the `e.Handled` so you know which condition is being checked, it all seems to work according to my testing.

Comment: thank you, that worked perfect!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13775002/832052) except you have the added requirement of allowing `-`

So try this

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))  //bypass control keys
    {
        int dashIndex = textBox1.Text.IndexOf('-');
        int dotIndex = textBox1.Text.IndexOf('.');
        int selectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        int selectionEnd = selectionStart + textBox1.SelectionLength;

        if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            if (dashIndex == 0 && selectionStart == 0 && selectionEnd == 0)
                e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '-')
        {
            if (dashIndex == -1)
            {
                if (selectionStart != 0)
                    e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
                e.Handled = !(selectionStart <= dashIndex && selectionEnd > dashIndex);
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '.')
        {
            if (dotIndex == -1)
                e.Handled = false;
            else
                e.Handled = !(selectionStart <= dotIndex && selectionEnd > dotIndex);
        }
        else
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried, it does not accept the dot and it accept more than one (-) no matter what is the index of (-) in the input

Comment: @Baibers Let's be honest, when I wrote this answer your question had `{'delete' , 'backspace' , one '.' , '-' , numbers '0 to 9'}`, you have since edited it. So one '-' is a new requirement, but you should be able to apply the same logic as the '.'. Also the code I posted does accept the dot (period) unless you're putting a different "dot"

Comment: I apologize, the textbox must only accept positive and negative doubles with backspace and delete , I am beginner and sometimes I explain things in a bad way

Comment: @Baibers I updated the answer according to the requirement. You have now made it clear that you only want floats with or without `-`. To be honest, you would be better off with a `NumericUpDown` which only allows numbers but you get scrolling arrows. But why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to enable the operator to edit a possibly negative number with exactly one decimal point.

Your proposal is to check every input character as soon as it is typed, and allow or forbid the character. This gives a rather clumsy user interface.

- Operator types 9876
- Oh no, this is the incorrect number, I need -76"
- The operator uses the arrow keys to go back to before the 7, type the minus sign (intermediate: 98-76), use the arrow key to go one to the left, and delete delete to remove the 98 (intermediate: 9-76, -76)

Copy paste other values "Price €76.12" and remove unwanted characters (76.12) is impossible.

The proper interface would be, to allow the operator everything, until he signals you that he finished editing the number. Usually this is an OK button, or if you want the enter button. Subscribe to the proper event, and handle the input only then:

```
public void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    string inputText = this.textBox1.Text;
    this.ProcessInput(inputText);
}

// or if you want: react on enter:
public void OnKeyPress(object sender, ...)
{
    // check if enter
    bool enterPressed = ...
    if (enterPressed)
    {
        this.ProcessInput(this.textBox1.Text);
    }
}

public void ProcessInput(string inputText)
{
    // check if the text can be converted to a double:
    if (double.TryParse(inputText, double result))
    {
         // text ok: do what you need to do
    }
    else
    {
         // text not ok: warn the operator
    }
}
```

Comment: I have many textboxes and many buttons that take the input from textboxes and work on, so I prefer to limit the input mistakes from beginning, but thank you anyway , I may need this in other dependent input forms

Comment: If you have button-texbox combinations, consider to create a usercontrol that contains this combination. Or consider to derive from text box and check the input in the derived class, so you can reuse the code for your other text boxes