# How to add text to cursor position in textbox

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox

I have a `Textbox` and I want to add text to the cursor position, how should I do it?

P.s. I know how to read cursor's position, but how do I add text to that position?

Comment: Why can't you add it?  Show us the code.

Comment: What technology? WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net?

Comment: I'm using windows Form application, i dont have code - i thing it will be 1-2 lines... I want to put some text in to textbox coursor position... I'm begginer :(

Comment: `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(textBox1.SelectionStart, "X");`

Comment: `-1` start doing some google / web searches beginner or not is no excuse for your own lack of effort

Answer (score 4):

It's duplicated with [How do I find the position of a cursor in a text box? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526540/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-a-cursor-in-a-text-box-c-sharp)

Just follow the line:

`myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text.Insert(myTextBox.SelectionStart, "Hello world");`

Comment: Assignment to .Text leads to resetting the position to the start of the text, which is unacceptable