# C# TextBox Override Arrow Key Select Function

Tags: c#, textbox

Basically, continuing from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193302/c-sharp-make-a-group-of-characters-in-a-textbox-behave-like-one-character), when the user presses `shift` + either left or right I need it to select the entire character group.

The current code I have (under the PreviewKeyDown Event):

```
string s;
int caretLocation = textBox1.SelectionStart;
string txt = textBox1.Text;
if (e.Shift) 
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        #region Right
        case Keys.Right:
            {
                s = txt.Substring(caretLocation);
                foreach (string combo in charCombinations)
                {
                    if (s.StartsWith(combo))
                    {
                        textBox1.SelectionLength = combo.Length - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            } 
        #endregion
        #region Left
        case Keys.Left:
            {
                s = txt.Substring(0, caretLocation);
                foreach (string combo in charCombinations)
                {
                    if (s.EndsWith(combo))
                    {
                        textBox1.SelectionStart = caretLocation - combo.Length + 1;
                        textBox1.SelectionLength = combo.Length + 1
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The first issue lies with the right key, where if there are two of such character groups in a row, the caret does not move right any further from the position shown below:

[image]

The second issue lies with the left key, where the left key selection just doesn't select the entire character:

[image]

For this case, the entire word `sin(` should be selected.

Thanks in advance!

`charCombinations` has been defined as:

```
    private static readonly string[] charCombinations = new string[] { "asinh(", "acosh", "atanh(",
        "sinh(", "cosh(", "tanh(", "asin(", "acos(", "atan(", "sin(", "cos(", "tan(", 
        "log(", "ln(", "PI", "e", "Phi"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add next text length to previous length.

I fixed your codes this model:

```
        case Keys.Right:
        {
            s = txt.Substring(caretLocation);

            foreach (string combo in charCombinations)
            {
                if (s.StartsWith(combo))
                {
                    textBox1.SelectionLength += combo.Length - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
```

The important line is:  `textBox1.SelectionLength += combo.Length - 1;`

in that I use `+=` instead `=`