# Get cursor position of winforms textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I get the current cursor (caret) position of a winforms textbox in .NET? SelectionStart only returns the start of the selected text (left side of the selection). Means this value is wrong if the cursor is at the right side of the selection.

---

To clarify: In .NET TextBox SelectionStart points to the left side of an selection, also when the caret is at the right side of the selection. This means in both pictures SelectionStart is 2, but the caret position is 2 in the first picture and 7 in the right picture.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the position of a cursor in a text box? C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526540/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-a-cursor-in-a-text-box-c-sharp)

Comment: What do you mean by "Means this value is wrong if the cursor is at the right side of the selection" ?  Does  `SelectionStart  + SelectionLength` helps?

Comment: @musefan: Please read the whole question! SelectionStart does not solve my problem.

Comment: For those (OP) who don't understand their own question, read this first: What happens when you have selected text, and you type something? it inserts at the start of the selection, therefore that must be where the caret position is. Regardless of which direction you select, the caret will be at the start of the selection

Comment: @Sriram: SelectionStart + SelectionLength should be corrent if the cursor is at the right side. But how can I determine at which side the cursor is?

Comment: @musefan: The difference is: I dont want to insert text, I want to know the numeric index.

Comment: *SelectionStart only returns the start of the selected text (left side of the selection)*  - no it's not. It returns the *current position* of caret in case when no text is selected or *selection start position* in case when some text is *selected*. So you can use it in both cases to calculate position anyway...

Comment: What? The cursor is technically always on the left side of a selection, which is why you use SelectionLength to get the right side position.

Comment: @user1027167: It was just an example to try and make it easier for you to understand what I am trying to say. The caret is **always** at the start of the selection. So the answer is to use `SelectionStart`. If that is not what you want, then you have a different question that isn't related to caret position at all, and I suggest you re-ask

Comment: @Fabjan: If you make a selection in a textbox (with mouse or keyboard) form the left to the right, than you can see a blinking caret at the right side of the blue selection. When you then read the values of SelectionStart, you will see that this value shows to the left side of the selection.

Comment: @user1027167 Updated my answer

Comment: @Fabjan: Thanks, so MSDN says "If no text is selected", but this is not the case for me.

Comment: @user1027167 No need to worry. Btw i've updated my answer so it's more suitable to your case (at least it *should be*).

Comment: @Fabjan: No! As I mentioned above, you can select the text from left to right and from right to left. In the first case the caret is at the end of the selection, in the second case the caret is at the beginning of the selection. So in the first case I have to use SelectionStart, in the second SelectionStart+SelectionLength. But how to distingiush these two cases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already stated, the `SelectionStart` property is not reliable to get the actual CARET position in a TextBox with a selection active. This is caused by the fact that this property points always at the selection start (clue: the name doesn't lie) and depending on how you select the text with the mouse the caret could be positioned on the LEFT or RIGHT side of the selection.

This code (tested with LinqPAD) shows an alternative

```
public class WinApi
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCaretPos(out System.Drawing.Point lpPoint);
}

TextBox t = new TextBox();
void Main()
{
    Form f = new Form();
    f.Controls.Add(t);
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
    b.Click += onClick;
    f.Controls.Add(b);
    f.ShowDialog();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
void onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start:" + t.SelectionStart + " len:" +t.SelectionLength);
    Point p = new Point();
    bool result = WinApi.GetCaretPos(out p);
    Console.WriteLine(p);
    int idx = t.GetCharIndexFromPosition(p);
    Console.WriteLine(idx);
}
```

The API `GetCaretPos` returns the point in client coordinates where the CARET is. You could return the index of the character after the position using the managed method `GetCharIndexFromPosition`. Of course you need to add a reference and a using to `System.Runtime.InteropServices`.

Not sure if there is some drawback to this solution and waiting if someone more expert can tell us if there is something wrong or unaccounted for.

Comment: This unfortunately only works if the TextBox has focus. So if the caret position for an unfocused TextBox is needed, this won't work (unless you swap the current focus to get the position, but that's an ugly hack).

Answer (score 1):

With the answer from Steve this is now my solution:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private extern static int GetCaretPos(out Point p);

...

// get current caret position
Point caret;
GetCaretPos(out caret);
int caretPosition = tbx.GetCharIndexFromPosition(caret);
```

Additionally (not part of my question) I am able to set the caret and text selection with following code. There also is a SetCaret function in user32.dll which didn't work for me. But surprisingly the Select() function supports negative values for selection length.

```
// determine if current caret is at beginning
bool caretAtBeginning = tbx.SelectionStart == caretIndex;

...

// set text selection and caret position
if (caretAtBeginning)
    tbx.Select(selStart + selLength, -selLength);
else
    tbx.Select(selStart, selLength);
```

<sub>Note: This post was extracted from the Question and posted on the OP's behalf.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you want the left side of the selection, you can use:

```
int index = textBox.SelectionStart;
```

If you want the right side of the selection, you can use:

```
int index = textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectionLength;
```

If you need to know which direction the text was selected then you could try tracking mouse down and mouse up events and comparing the cursor positions when the events fired.

For example:

```
// On mouse down event.
int mouseDownX = MousePosition.X;

// On mouse up event.
int mouseUpX = MousePosition.X;

// Check direction.
if(mouseDownX < mouseUpX)
{
    // Left to Right selection.
    int index = textBox.SelectionStart;   
}
else
{
    // Right to Left selection.
    int index = textBox.SelectionStart + textBox.SelectionLength;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that might be a workaround. So I also have to track the keyboard. If there is no better solution, I have to take this. Thanks for this idea.

Answer (score 0):

This may come in use to someone:

```
int lastSelectionStart = 0;

int getCaretPosition()
{
    if (tbx.SelectionLength == 0)
    {
        lastSelectionStart = tbx.SelectionStart;
        return lastSelectionStart;
    }
    else
    {
        if (tbx.SelectionStart == lastSelectionStart)
        {
            return tbx.SelectionStart + tbx.SelectionLength;
        }
        else
        {
            return lastSelectionStart - tbx.SelectionLength;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the mouse or move an arrow key button inside a TextBox, your cursor will be moved to a new location and the location will be recorded in this variable.

```
textBox1.SelectionStart
```

The value is character count starting from 0 at the beginning of the TextBox to the location of your cursor. If you carefully code it, you'll make it work correctly. To highlight selection, you should use this function to avoid confusion.

```
textBox1.Select(start, length);
```

where

```
int start = textBox1.SelectionStart;
int length = textBox1.SelectionStart+textBox1.SelectionLength;
```