# How to detect if cursor position is between certain characters in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I'm trying to make a editor application in Winforms that allows me to have automatic bracket alignment. I currently have a richtextbox that creates a closing bracket when I press the opening bracket.

The next thing I want to do is when my cursor is between the opening and closing brackets and I press enter, that the closing bracket gets places 2 lines further then the opening bracket and that the cursor gets placed one line further with a tab inserted.

My main question is, how to I detect if the cursor is between 2 certain characters? The placement of the closing bracket and cursor is optional.

Comment: Why can't you check `SelectionStart` property? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526540/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-a-cursor-in-a-text-box-c-sharp

Comment: I wouldn't know how to check that

Comment: The link you put in your comment is how to put text at the cursor. I need to check if the cursor is between certain characters

Comment: Get the index from it, do +1 and -1 you'll get start and end point index. Insert your string in-between. I cannot write an example code as I'm accessing so from phone.

Comment: An example code would be handy yes. Since I can't see how this can check if my cursor is between { and }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void addTabToText()
    {
      int caretPos = myTextBox.SelectionStart; //Get the start position
      if(caretPos != 0 && caretPos!=myTextBox.Text.Length) //if not at the end or start
      {
        if(myTextBox.Text[caretPos-1]=='(' && myTextBox.Text[caretPos]==')'){
          myTextBox.Text = myTextBox.Text.Insert(caretPos, "  ");
          //to change cursor position
          myTextBox.SelectionStart = caretPos + 2; // length of string added 
          myTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

Here, I'm checking for the previous char and the next char, using the `SelectionStart`. This you can call from `Enter` pressed event.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work. The only thing I changed is: myTextBox is now editorTB; ( and ) are now { and }. I call the function in the keypress event.

Comment: What problem you are getting? what's the error/output?

Comment: I don't get any error/output. It just doesn't do anything. I think it's because the check for the caretpos is incorrect and it never is True

Comment: Can you debug and tell me the value of `caretPos` for one correct input?

Comment: The value of caretPos changes everytime. lets say I have a line of text like this one: "Line of text {}" then caretPos will be equal to 14. If I have a line of text like this one: "One more line {}" then caretPos is equal to 15

Comment: I just checked it. If I put editorTB.AppendText("TEXT") instead of editorTB.Text.Insert(caretPos + "text") it works, but it doesn't place it at the cursor

Comment: This means that it does work, the editorTB.Text.Insert(caretpos, "text"); just doesn't work

Comment: This should work, got to know that `Insert` returns a new string instead of modifying the old string. Also added for changing cursor position, check it out.