# TextBox handled doesn't work in some case

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have textbox and when i create that form i pass some values and then i prevent user to input some things into textbox based on passed values with this code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!brojevi && char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    if (!slova && char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    if (!znakovi && char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) || !znakovi && char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    if (!razmak && char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    if (maxKaraktera != -1 && (textBox1.Text.Length + 1) > maxKaraktera)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (maxBroj != -1 && Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) > maxBroj)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Problem is that i enabled `brojevi` and set `maxBroj` to `10`

Now when i try typing some char, it checks and see that `slova` is not `true`, set `e.Handled = true` and `return` and in my textbox that char is not imputed which is ok.

But when i try inserting number which is greater than 10 (let's say 12), it goes to `if` statement where it checks `if(maxBroj != -1 && Convert.ToDoube(textBox1.Text) > maxBroj)` and it enters it, set `e.Handled = true` and `return` but number is implemented in textbox.

Why this happens?

EDIT: Code from creating form and form that has `textbox`

Creating from:

```
MessageBoxWithValue msg = new MessageBoxWithValue("Unesite kolicinu", "Unesite zeljenu kolicinu. Maksimum: " + aa.maxKolicina.ToString());

msg.brojevi = true;
msg.maxBroj = aa.maxKolicina;
msg.ShowDialog();
if(msg.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    kol = Convert.ToDouble(msg.returnValue);
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Here is `MessageBoxWithValue` form:

```
public partial class MessageBoxWithValue : Form
{
    public bool brojevi = false;
    public bool slova = false;
    public bool znakovi = false;
    public bool razmak = false;

    public double maxBroj = -1;
    public int maxKaraktera = -1;

    public string returnValue;

    public MessageBoxWithValue(string naslov, string opis)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = naslov;
        label1.Text = opis;
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!brojevi && char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (!slova && char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (!znakovi && char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) || !znakovi && char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (!razmak && char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (maxKaraktera != -1 && (textBox1.Text.Length + 1) > maxKaraktera)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (maxBroj != -1 && Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) > maxBroj)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            Uspesno();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uspesno();
    }

    private void Uspesno()
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        returnValue = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is your logic clearly is missing something.. however, this isnt a minimal viable code.. its hard to know what influences most of those variables so its difficult to follow exactly whats going on

Comment: Use the debugger, step through the statements and check what happens at every step of the way. I suspect maybe textBox1.Text contains the old value until the handler(s) exit.

Comment: Having the variable names in Hungarian does not really help (well, most likely it *does* help you, but it's harder to guess what you are trying to achieve that way) - could you translate those to meaningful english variable names? If you are having a hard time translating them to meaningful names, you might be lacking concepts.

Comment: I added whole code. If you need i can translate variables to English.

Answer (score 1):

> But when i try inserting number which is greater than 10 (let's say 12), it goes to if statement where it checks `if(maxBroj != -1 && Convert.ToDoube(textBox1.Text) > maxBroj)` and it enters it, set `e.Handled = true` and return but number is implemented in textbox.

I hope I've got your issue right. You are trying to filter numbers by their values (e.g. `maxBroj` is set to 10) and you are expecting

```
if (maxBroj != -1 && Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) > maxBroj)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

not to allow entering a number `>10`. Unfortunately this will not work as intended, since `textBox1.Text` won't be set until the `KeyPress` event handler has finished.

Let's say you are entering `14`. When the first `KeyPress` event is raised (`1`), `textBox1.Text` is empty. You are returning from

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
{
    return;
}
```

Afterwards `textBox1.Text` is set to `"1"`. Then the second `KeyPress` event is raised. `textBox1.Text` is `"1"`, hence the method won't enter the block

```
if (maxBroj != -1 && Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) > maxBroj)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

Afterwards `textBox1.Text` will be set to `"14"`, but this is too late for your validation.

You'll have to calculate the expected new value. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526540/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-a-cursor-in-a-text-box-c-sharp) on how to insert the new character in the existing string.

Comment: Now i see where is problem but didn't catch you at how to solve it. How should i approach it then?

Comment: @AleksaRistic I was a bit in a rush, will try to extend my answer later.